# How to use ConfigService inside TypeOrmModule.forFeature?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I want to use NestJS `ConfigService` inside my `TypeOrmModule.forFeature` to retrieve some vars inside the .env file. How can I do it? When creating a connection I use the `forRootAsync` but I can't find anything like it for configurations

My Module:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User, Faker]),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User], ConnectionName.Secondary), <== use ConfigService here
    RedisModule,
  ],
  controllers: [UsersController],
  providers: [UsersService],
  exports: [UsersService],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `forFeatureAsync`, and honestly you probably don't want there to be. When you use `forFeature()` with a connection name, that means you need to use `@InjectRepository()` with a connection name as well, and as there's no way to inject  service into a decorator, you'd end up hitting another wall here. Along with that, the `name` that you pass to `forFeature()` should be defined away from the config service. You can still pass a name to TypeORM from the config service in the async options, but there should also be a `name` property on the same level as `useFactory` in the `forRootAsync()` options

Comment: thank you very much! So using an enum/constant in the way i'm doing right now is the right way? If yes then I'm very grateful for your answer.

Comment: That's _a_ right way. There's not just _one_ right way